# How to find the image of a region under a matrix?

Tags: regions

I want to write code that, given a matrix, finds the image of a unit disk under that matrix. I googled this and I could not find much but this seems like such a simple task. I found the command TransformedRegion but it does not allow a matrix as it's second argument.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Edit:seems to work

```
TransformedRegion[
 Disk[{0, 0}, 
  1], {x*Indexed[#, 1] + z*Indexed[#, 2], 
   y*Indexed[#, 1] + e*Indexed[#, 2]} &]
```

Comment: With respect to your recently deleted question, try `Eliminate[{w == Tr[A1 . A1 . A2], x == Tr[A1], y == Tr[A2], z == Tr[A1 . A2], Det[A1] == 1, Det[A2] == 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** If you have a 2X2 matrix `mat` to transform the coordinates, use `Dot[mat, #]&` as the second argument in `TransformedRegion`:

```
mat = {{x, y}, {w, z}};
TransformedRegion[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], mat.# &]
```

> ```
> Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, {{x^2 + y^2, w x + y z}, {w x + y z, w^2 + z^2}}]
> ```

**Original answer:** If you have a 3X3 transformation matrix `tm`, use `TransformationFunction @ tm` as the second argument in `TransformedRegion`:

```
tm = {{3, 3, 6}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}};

MatrixForm @ tm
```

[image]

```
transformeddisk = TransformedRegion[Disk[], TransformationFunction @ tm]
```

> ```
>  Ellipsoid[{6, 1}, {{18, 3}, {3, 1}}]
> ```

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker @ Red}], Opacity[.7], Red, Disk[], 
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker @ Green}], Green, transformeddisk}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `GeometricTransformation` instead of `TransformedRegion`:

```
transformeddisk2 = GeometricTransformation[Disk[], TransformationFunction @ tm]
```

> ```
> GeometricTransformation[Disk[{0, 0}], {{{3, 3}, {0, 1}}, {6, 1}}]
> ```

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker @ Red}], Opacity[.7], Red, Disk[], 
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker @ Green}], Green, transformeddisk2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am confused, how are you applying a $3\times 3$ matrix on vectors in $\mathbb{R}^@$? It has to a be a $2 \times 2$ matrix to make sense, no?

Comment: I think I figured it out, could you look at the post edit please?

Comment: @2132123, please see the update.